# Exporting Data from Hybris via Impex through Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I have Impex to export the data from Hybris via ImpexExport in HAC. (It's working fine)
I want to perform the same thing via Groovy Script, read the same Impex via groovy script and save the exported zip file at a particular location.

**Impex**
INSERT_UPDATE Region;isocodeShort;isocode;country(isocode)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exportService` to acheive your purpose :

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.ExportConfig
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.ExportResult
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.ExportService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.StreamBasedImpExResource


ExportService exportService = spring.getBean("exportService")


final ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream("INSERT_UPDATE Region;isocode[unique=true];isocodeShort;country(isocode)".getBytes("UTF-8"));

final ExportConfig config = new ExportConfig();
config.setScript(new StreamBasedImpExResource(baos, "UTF-8"));
config.setValidationMode(ExportConfig.ValidationMode.STRICT);
config.setEncoding("UTF-8");
exportedData =  exportService.exportData(config).getExportedData()
```

This will create an ExportedModel media, to get the download URL of this media you can use: `exportedData.getDownloadURL()`